# Code signing error ("object file format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable") in Game Salad IPA

Tags: ipa, gamesalad

We are using GameSalad to develop games for iOS. we have developed one app and while generating IPA we are getting below error.

We have same error while uploading application:

> Code Signing Error 1: /var/folders/gp/_32pgwv96m1gsyj88zcvqpb40000gn/T/GameSalad1/1/TTH_V2.app: replacing existing signature codesign_allocate: object: /private/var/folders/gp/_32pgwv96m1gsyj88zcvqpb40000gn/T/GameSalad1/1/TTH_V2.app/TTHV2 malformed object (unknown load command 41) /var/folders/gp/_32pgwv96m1gsyj88zcvqpb40000gn/T/GameSalad1/1/TTH_V2.app: object file format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable
>
> Make sure your provisioning profile, developer certificate, and WWDR certificate are installed, valid, not expired or duplicated, and signed with a private key in the keychain on the computer you are signing with.

Mac version : 10.8.5 x-code : 5.1.1 Gamesalad version : 0.11.0.14 beta

Answer (score 0):

Whilst this might not be ideal, if you can get hold of the IPA you can manually sign it with a mac application called iRe-Sign - always does a great job. It's available here:

https://github.com/maciekish/iReSign